# Send message from main process to renderer and receive response synchronously?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm trying add a custom dynamic context menu to electron application (at the moment by the means of [`electron-context-menu`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu)). For it to be dynamic it requires information about the section of the app it's clicked on. Only renderer process can give that information. Therefor I need somehow send request from main process to the renderer and receive the answer synchronously.

Is there a way to do so? Or maybe there is a better way to achieve this?

My renderer process in isolation mode, therefore can't be used `remote` module.
I can receive synchronous answers to requests sent from renderer to main process via `ipcRenderer`, but don't know any means do the same from main to render process.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with electron specifically, but "Therefor I need somehow send request from main process to the renderer and receive the answer synchronously" smells like a non-sequitur. Javascript (and UIs in general) are event-driven asynchronous systems, why does it *have* to be synchronous? (not the DV btw)

Comment: Well, because it would have to be done during `context-menu` event in main process. Of course I'm open for any other suggestions how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that `contextmenu` event in renderer fires before main process receives `context-menu` event...so it allows use this method:

1. In renderer listen for [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event on window, gather
   information about the element it was clicked on.
2. Send that information to main process via [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer)
3. In main process listen for [`context-menu`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/spellchecker#how-do-i-put-the-results-of-the-spellchecker-in-my-context-menu) event and store received [`params`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag/#event-context-menu)
   information in a global variable
4. In main process also listen for a message from rendered via [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main). Once received message, use the provided information from the message and `params` stored in global variable to display the menu.